# Prestashop multiple modals JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, prestashop

Currently, I work on a Prestashop module and I use AJAX methods but I don't know why my code doesn't work.

When I click on the button of the modal window, nothing happens. I think that the problem is that there are 3 modals but I don't known how to fix this problem.

This is the HTML code (with Smarty) :

```
{foreach from=$array item=result}
                    {*$result|@var_dump*}
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="{$result.image}" class="img-responsive center-block"/></td>
                        <td>
                            {$result.title_fr}<br/>
                            <small class="text-muted">{$result.content_fr}</small>
                            <br>{$result.brand.title_fr}
                        </td>
                        <td><code>{$result.code}</code></td>
                        <td>
                            <p>{$result.id}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="buttonCatalog" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#img_{$result.id}">
                                <i class="icon-camera-retro"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="buttonCatalog" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#text_{$result.id}">
                                <i class="icon-file-text"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" id="buttonCatalog" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#full_{$result.id}">
                                <i class="icon-camera-retro" ></i> + <i class="icon-file-text"></i>
                            </a>
                            {*foreach from=$result.id item=id*}
                                {*$id|@var_dump*}
                                <!-- Modal window for the product images. -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="img_{$result.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                     aria-labelledby="ModalLabelImage" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabelImage">{$modalTitle}</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>{$modalImageExplain}</p>
                                                <p id="alertMessage">{$modalExplain}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <label for="again" id="notAgain"><input id="again" type="checkbox" /> {$modalAgain}</label>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                        data-dismiss="modal">{$modalCancel}
                                                </button><button class="btn btn-success" id="submitImage" data-action="{$urlAddImage}"
                                                        data-idProduct={$result.id}>{$modalDefaultPrice}</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal window for the product description. -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="text_{$result.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                     aria-labelledby="ModalLabelImage" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabelImage">{$modalTitle}</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>{$modalTextExplain}</p>
                                                <p id="alertMessage">{$modalExplain}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <label for="again" id="notAgain"><input id="again" type="checkbox" /> {$modalAgain}</label>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                        data-dismiss="modal">{$modalCancel}
                                                </button><button class="btn btn-success" id="submitText" data-action="{$urlAddText}"
                                                        data-idProduct={$result.id}>{$modalDefaultPrice}</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Modal window for the product description and image. -->
                                <div class="modal fade" id="full_{$result.id}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                     aria-labelledby="ModalLabelImage" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabelImage">{$modalTitle}</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                <p>{$modalFullExplain}</p>
                                                <p id="alertMessage">{$modalExplain}</p>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <label for="again" id="notAgain"><input id="again" type="checkbox" /> {$modalAgain}</label>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                                        data-dismiss="modal">{$modalCancel}
                                                </button><button class="btn btn-success" id="submitFull" data-action="{$urlAddFull}"
                                                        data-idProduct={$result.id}>{$modalDefaultPrice}</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {*/foreach*}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {/foreach}
```

This is the JavaScript code :

```
$('#submitImage').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').empty();

    var url = $(this).data('action');
    var idProduct = $(this).data('idproduct');

    var query = $.post(url, {
        addImage: idProduct
    }, function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });

    $('#image').modal('toggle');
});
$('#submitText').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').empty();

    var url = $(this).data('action');
    var idProduct = $(this).data('idproduct');

    var query = $.post(url, {
        addText: idProduct
    }, function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });

    $('#text').modal('toggle');
});
$('#submitFull').on('click', function() {
    $('#result').empty();

    var url = $(this).data('action');
    var idProduct = $(this).data('idproduct');

    var query = $.post(url, {
        addFull: idProduct
    }, function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
    });

    $('#full').modal('toggle');
});
```

Anybody can help me please ?

Comment: the javascript is inside an on ready or on load, or at least after the elements in the code?

Comment: Yep, I have gived only the part which is used for the modals. I use here : `code`$(function() { ... }`code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code shown you don't have an element id result to show the data when in javascript you have `$('#result').html(data);`.
also, for example, there is no `$('#image')`, maybe you mean

```
$('#img_'+idProduct).modal('toggle');
```

Btw, if $array can have more than one element, you should the jQuery to bind to the class and not the id. id should be unique. For example: use submitImage in the class, not id, and then change the javascript to:

```
$( ".submitImage" ).each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function(){
          $('#result').empty();

          var url = $(this).data('action');
          var idProduct = $(this).data('idproduct');

          var query = $.post(url, {
              addImage: idProduct
          }, function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
       });

       $('#img_'+idProduct).modal('toggle');
    });
});
```